# JavaScript Not Advancing to the Next IF Statement

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out why my program will not move to the if statements after my first one where score=0. When I find the first city the second if statement does not fire, bringing up my alert window saying that we should find the second city. I am not sure why the if statement where score=1 is not activating.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>

<script>

var map;
      var score;
      score = 0;
      function initMap() {
        var chicago = {lat: 41.8781, lng: -87.6298};
        var indianapolis = {lat: 39.7684, lng: -86.1581};
        var oklahomaCity = {lat: 35.4819, lng: -97.5084};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0},
          zoom: 1
});
        var chicagoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: chicago,  


});

        var oklahomaCityMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: oklahomaCity,
});

        var indianapolisMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: indianapolis,

});

if (score==0) {
    chicagoMarker.setMap(map);
    chicagoMarker.setVisible(false);
    window.alert("Find my first city!");
    map.addListener('bounds_changed',function(){
        zoom = map.getZoom();
        console.log(zoom);
        if (zoom ==2 && map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Good Start!");
        }
        if (zoom ==3 && map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Keep Going!");
        }
        if (zoom ==4 && map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Getting Closer!");
        }
        if (zoom ==5 && map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Closer!");
        }
        if (zoom ==6 && map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Keep Going!");
        }
        if (zoom ==7 && map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Almost There!");
        }
        if (zoom ==8 && map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("You found Chicago! Your Score is: 1");
            score = 1;
        }
    })
};


if (score==1) {
    oklahomaCityMarker.setMap(map)
    oklahomaCityMarker.setVisible(false);
    window.alert("Find my second city!");
    map.addListener('bounds_changed',function(){
        zoom = map.getZoom();
        console.log(zoom);
        if (zoom ==2 && map.getBounds().contains(oklahomaCityMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Good Start!");
        }
        if (zoom ==3 && map.getBounds().contains(oklahomaCityMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Keep Going!");
        }
        if (zoom ==4 && map.getBounds().contains(oklahomaCityMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Getting Closer!");
        }
        if (zoom ==5 && map.getBounds().contains(oklahomaCityMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Closer!");
        }
        if (zoom ==6 && map.getBounds().contains(oklahomaCityMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Keep Going!");
        }
        if (zoom ==7 && map.getBounds().contains(oklahomaCityMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Almost There!");
        }
        if (zoom ==8 && map.getBounds().contains(oklahomaCityMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("You found Chicago! Your Score is: 1");
            google.maps.event.ClearListeners('bounds_changed');
        }
    })
    score = score + 1;
    google.maps.event.ClearListeners('bounds_changed');

};

if (score==2) {
    indianapolisMarker.setMap(map)
    indianapolisMarker.setVisible(false);
    window.alert("Find my first city!");
    map.addListener('bounds_changed',function(){
        zoom = map.getZoom();
        console.log(zoom);
        if (zoom ==2 && map.getBounds().contains(indianapolisMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Good Start!");
        }
        if (zoom ==3 && map.getBounds().contains(indianapolisMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Keep Going!");
        }
        if (zoom ==4 && map.getBounds().contains(indianapolisMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Getting Closer!");
        }
        if (zoom ==5 && map.getBounds().contains(indianapolisMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Closer!");
        }
        if (zoom ==6 && map.getBounds().contains(indianapolisMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Keep Going!");
        }
        if (zoom ==7 && map.getBounds().contains(indianapolisMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("Almost There!");
        }
        if (zoom ==8 && map.getBounds().contains(indianapolisMarker.getPosition())){
            window.alert("You found Chicago! Your Score is: 2");
        }
    })
    score = score + 1;
    google.maps.event.ClearListeners('bounds_changed');

};
    }
</script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCuvsCAF0gVmwv6AF0SoA3xBjV66RG4r7o&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 5K of code for just a couple of lines, why?

Comment: hardcore alert code =)

Comment: why not call `map.getBounds().contains(chicagoMarker.getPosition())` once? and store the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't move to the next `if` because the `window.alert` statement freezes the program execution until you dismiss it. Consider using a non-blocking popup component, like [jQuery-ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Bootstrap-ui modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for example.

Comment: Is there a way I can close that alert so that I can move on to the next statement?

Comment: No, only the user can dismiss it. I've updated my answer. Consider using a different notification system that doesn't freezes the code execution.

Comment: so even when the user closes it, the code will not be able to move on to the next statement

Comment: No, when user dismiss the popup the code execution continues. However you shouldn't use those alerts anyway. And also you code is testing the `zoom` property which is different for all if statements that you are testing, so, it won't alert more than once per event.